# How to get values with Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can i get values from value pos:

```js
var pos = (59.9477, 59.9477)
var arr = pos.replace(/[^\d|,]/g, "").split(",");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: is `pos` a string??? And what is your desired output??

Comment: Do you mean `var pos = '(59.9477, 59.9477)'` ? Also what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `pos` should be a string.
2. You have to exclude `.` too from being removed.
3. The `|` (or) inside the set has no use.

```js
var pos = "(59.9477, 59.9477)";
var arr = pos.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, "").split(",");
console.log(arr);
```

**Another way to do it:**

You can use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get the result using this regular expression `/\d*\.?\d+/g`. Like this:

```js
var pos = "(59.9477, 59.9477)";
var arr = pos.match(/\d*\.?\d+/g);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Just a small type in the first snippet: you need to escape the period there too: \.

Comment: @MacPrawn The only thing that needs escaping inside the set is `]`.

Comment: "." is a reserved character, so you're actually going to replace everything that is not a digit, a comma, or "one character" - no?

Comment: @MacPrawn Inside a [**set**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), `.` will be the _litteral `.`_ not the _any-character `.`_, `/` will be `/` not the end of regex, .... the only thing that cause problems is `]` and `-`!

Answer (score 1):

> How can i get values from value pos:

Based on your code, and your question with `var pos = (59.9477, 59.9477)`, you should know that `console.log(pos) // => 59.9477` and `typeof post // => "number"` and replace method and regex is for String type only. So I guess your variable could be `var pos = "(59.9477, 59.9477)"` which is String.

`var arr = pos.replace(/[^\d|,]/g, "").split(",");` your regex `/[^\d|,]/g`, this mean match all except number and comma, but I think you would want to keep the decimal right? Other will you will get back `["599477", "599477"]`. I guess you want ["59.9477", "59.9477"], if so your code should be `var arr = pos.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").split(",");`

Note: you do not need `|` for `or` when using NOT `[^]`

Answer (score 0):

Just use quotes, instead of ():

```
var pos = "59.9477, 59.9477";
var arr = pos.replace(/[^\d|,]/g, "").split(",");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: my problom is that iam getting this value with quotes in REST json , and i need to get theese lat and long values out of quotes?

Comment: So what's your data ? a string, array or json object ? there is no such thing as values between () in javascript. () is used to define or execute functions only..